# ng-file-upload validation rules don't run and form returns $valid:true in all cases

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have a scenario where I need to generate a upload form for each object in an array. I'm using the [ng-file-upload plugin](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to handle the uploads and the form validation.

The problem is that the validation works perfectly on my local machine, but the validation is not triggered when deployed on the server.

I've made absolutely sure that there are no deployment errors, tested in multiple browsers, cleared caches, etc. The code is 100% the same. Only the results differ for whatever reason.

Viewing the form element `$scope` in DevTools after the form has been submitted you can see that `$valid` and the various validators are present and set to `true`, but they are not being toggled to `false` when the validation should fail:

`file: Object {
     $asyncValidators: Object
     $dirty: true
     $error: Object
     $invalid: false
     $name: "file"
     $ngfValidations: Array[11]
     $pending: undefined
     $pristine: false
     $touched: false
     $untouched: true
     $valid: true
}`

This is the code in the view (simplified slightly):

```
<div ng-repeat="point in endpoints">
    <div class="panel-body" >
        <form name="uploadForm">
            <div class="media-uploader button drop-box"
                ng-model="file"
                name="file"
                ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'"
                ngf-accept="{{point.endpoint.type.acceptedFormat.join('/*,') }}/*"
                ngf-select="uploadForm.$valid && submitUpload($file, point)"
                ngf-drop="submitUpload($file, point)"
                ngf-max-size="{{ maxFileUploadSize }}"
                ngf-pattern="{{ point.endpoint.type.acceptedFormat.join('/*,') }}/*"
                ngf-max-duration="{{ (point.timeslots * 15)+tolerance }}"
                ngf-validate = "{width: {min: {{ point.endpoint.format.width }}, max:{{ point.endpoint.format.width }}},
                                height: {min: {{ point.endpoint.format.height }}, max: {{ point.endpoint.format.height }}}
                                }">

                <p>Click or drag to select images and video</p>
            </div>
         </form>
         <div class="has-error" >
             <div ng-show="uploadForm.file.$error.maxHeight || uploadForm.file.$error.maxWidth ">
                 Media must be {{ point.endpoint.format.width }} &times; {{ point.endpoint.format.height }}px
             </div>
             <div ng-show="uploadForm.file.$error.maxSize">
                 Max upload size exceeded the maximum allowed size is 200MB
             </div>
             <div ng-show="uploadForm.file.$error.pattern ">
                 This endpoint only allows {{ point.endpoint.type.acceptedFormat.join(', ') }} uploads
             </div>
             <div ng-show="uploadForm.file.$error.maxDuration ">
                 Your video exceeds the maximum allowed time of {{ point.timeslots * 15 }} seconds.
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

As I mentioned: The code works 100% on my local machine, but the form doesn't run the validation when it's up on the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Print the content of the uploadForm.file.$error after file is selected that might give you a  clue.

Comment: @danial Already tried. It's as if the validation just doesn't run. $error object remains empty and $valid remains true. I'm thinking it might have to do with the ng-repeat and the form scope. Will post my answer if I find a solution.

Comment: Could be try it with just one endpoints and see if that makes a difference